# Android ListView dividers

Tags: android, listview, separator, divider

If an entry in ListView is disabled, dividers won't be drawn around it. But if we set dividerHeight to something large, we can notice they are still there... but just invisible.

So, two questions:

- how to get rid of them, fully?
- is there any way to style those hidden dividers from themes and take advantage of this feature? We can adjust `<item name="android:listDivider">`, maybe there's some kind of `<item name="android:invisibleListDivider">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get rid of them, fully?

I'm not 100% sure but I would say that it cant be done.

> is there any way to style those hidden dividers from themes and take advantage of this feature? We can adjust , maybe there's some kind of ?

There is `@android:drawable/empty`. `@null` should work as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the second part. What I mean is whether we can adjust custom style to the invisible divider, like for example give it another drawable as the background.